# Dynamic specification of namespace for static classes/class instances

Tags: apex, managed-package, namespace

Ordinarily, when referencing a static class in a managed package from outside, we would do this:

```
ns.Class1.foo();
```

Now, if the `ns` package is somehow uninstalled, this code should stop working, I assume. How would I be able to make sure that this code is executed only when the package is in the org?

Also, can I build the above code in an org in which the managed package does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex does not include [full reflection capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) so it is hard to do what you want. You can instantiate a class using e.g. [Type.forName('...').newInstance()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) but there is then no way to invoke methods by name.

If you are willing to add quite a lot of code you can work-around the problem using techniques such as the one described in [Breaking managed package dependencies](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/breaking-managed-package-dependencies/). But that is quite painful.

Comment: Okay, so now that I know I have to hardcode it, the question is, will the build break if `ns` disappears? Or will it still compile? If `ns` isn't there, and I put an if check based on which that hardcoded function call is not executed in its absence, it shouldn't be an issue, or should it?

Comment: It would add a dependency if you add any code which refers to managed package

Comment: The platform compiles on demand so in general the compilation will fail if you have a reference to a namespace/class that is no longer present. But if you put the call in a class that you only instantiate via `Type.forName` when the namespace is present you can probably get it to work.

Comment: Even if I instantiate it with Type.forName I'd have to cast it to the actual class type to call any method... this casting will raise an error in any case.

Comment: I'm suggesting making the call entirely in the `Type.forName` instantiated class, but that requires a lot of glue code.

Comment: Well the good news is I have access to the managed package. So I can think about it. Thanks for the help.